# Не могу обработать исключения при обновление

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

День добрый, проблема в том что при обновлении у меня в обязательном порядке запрашивает что бы я что то ввел в поля username или же email, но я хочу обновить только данные о avatar без изменения других полей.

View.py

```
    def patch(self, request):
    profile = request.user
    serializer = UserProfileUpdateSerializer(profile, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
class MangalibUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
username = models.CharField('username', max_length=55, blank=False)
email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, blank=False)

is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

is_translator = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.email}'


class MangaUser(MangalibUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True)
    lvl = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

serializer.py

```
class UserProfileUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = MangaUser
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'avatar']
```

И ошибка которая выходит если в поля username и email я не ввожу никаких данных

```
{
"username": [
    "This field is required."
],
"email": [
    "This field is required."
]
```

}